# Customer Register - Identify Existing Email

Tags: shopify

I'm trying on Shopify when a user is trying to create an account, to verify if the email that the user picked already exists, the theme I'm using is Debut. So far I've had 0 success with this.

```
<div class="page-width">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half medium-up--push-one-quarter">

      <div class="input-form form-vertical">
        {% form 'create_customer' %}

          <h1 class="text-center">{{ 'customer.register.title' | t }}</h1>

          {%- if form.errors -%}
            <div class="form-message form-message--error">
              {{ form.errors | default_errors }}
            </div>
          {%- endif -%}

          <label for="FirstName">{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}</label>
          <input type="text" name="customer[first_name]" id="FirstName" {% if form.first_name %}value="{{ form.first_name }}"{% endif %} autofocus>

          <label for="LastName">{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}</label>
          <input type="text" name="customer[last_name]" id="LastName" {% if form.last_name %}value="{{ form.last_name }}"{% endif %}>

          <label for="Email">{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}</label>
          <input type="email" name="customer[email]" id="Email" class="{% if form.errors contains 'email' %} input--error{% endif %}" {% if form.email %} value="{{ form.email }}"{% endif %} autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">

          <label for="CreatePassword">{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}</label>
          <input type="password" name="customer[password]" id="CreatePassword" class="{% if form.errors contains 'password' %} input--error{% endif %}">
        
          <label for="CreatePassword2">Repeat Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="customer[password]" id="CreatePassword2" class="{% if form.errors contains 'password' %} input--error{% endif %}">

          <p class="text-center">
            <input type="submit" value="{{ 'customer.register.submit' | t }}" class="btn">
          </p>
        

        {% endform %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought that the part of

```
{{ form.errors | default_errors }}
```

Would return an error when the email is duplicate but it does nothing and the user just gets redirected to the main page. Any idea of how this can be accomplished? Thank you

Comment: What exactly happens if you use the customer sign-up form to sign-up a customer with the same email more than once? You are not explaining that, and then following up with why the response is not satisfactory. I am assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that Shopify prohibits signing up by reusing an email address, but perhaps I am wrong. What does happen?

Comment: Nothing, it brings you back to the register page :\

Comment: So no duplicate customer is entered, the original one still exists, and your whole problem is just in rendering out an error message? The fact that you are redirecting may be killing the error message, would it not?

Comment: Yes, seems like it, but I can't find any code to redirect the user anywhere.